# Initializing union of two structs with common initial sequnce

Tags: c, language-lawyer, unions

**QUESTION**: If union contains two structs with common initial sequnce of compatible types is the behavior well defined if we initialize some part of the initial sequence using one struct and the rest of the part of the initial sequence using another struct?

Consider the following code fragment:

```
union u_t{
    struct {
        int i1;
        int i2;
    } s1;

    struct {
        int j1;
        int j2;
    } s2;
};

int main(){
    union u_t *u_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*u_ptr));
    u_ptr -> s1.i1 = 10;
    u_ptr -> s2.j2 = 11;

    printf("%d\n", u_ptr -> s2.j1 + u_ptr -> s1.i2); //prints 21
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdb03f95978e9faf)

The question is if the "printing 21" behavior is well-defined. The Standard `N1570 6.5.2.3(p6)` specifies the following:

> if a union contains several structures that share a common initial
>   sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one
>   of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial
>   part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type
>   of the union is visible.

So it would be ok to inspect the common initial sequence (in this case the whole struct). But the problem is that in this case the union seems to contain the `s2` object with `j2` being the only initialized member.

I think we end up ***unspecified*** behavior since we only initialized `s2.j2` while `s2.j1` did not so it should contain unspecified value.

Comment: The allocated memory doesn't even have an effective type of `union u_t` or any of the structs. It is just 2 `int`s.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer _The allocated memory doesn't even have an effective type of union u_t or any of the structs_ What do you mean? Can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5p6

Comment: I don't get why you think that this is an undefined behavior. Structs share the same memory in a union therefore its quite logical that assigning a value to `i1` will automatically assign the value to `j1` since they're using the same memory space.

Comment: The effective type is indeed just 2 integers and as long as they are accessed as such, it should be fine. The compiler is not allowed to do any form of aliasing optimizations here. Regarding type punning through unions, it is supposedly well-defined as per 6.5.2.3/3.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer _It is just 2 `int`s_ I agree. So applying strict aliasing rules along with "type punning" as @Lundin mentioned in the answer we have well defined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regarding aliasing:**

The common initial sequence is only concerned with aliasing of the two struct types. That's not a problem here and your two structs are even compatible types and therefore pointers to them may alias without using any tricks. Dissecting C11 6.2.7:

> 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>   Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. /--/ Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements:
>
> If one is declared with a tag, the
>   other shall be declared with the same tag.

Neither struct is declared with a tag here.

> If both are completed anywhere within their
>   respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply:

They are both completed (defined).

> there shall
>   be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of
>   corresponding members are declared with compatible types;

This holds true for these structs.

> if one member of the pair is
>   declared with an alignment specifier, the other is declared with an equivalent alignment
>   specifier; and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared
>   with the same name.

Alignment specifiers do not apply.

> For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the
>   same order.

This holds true.

The conclusion is that your both structs are of compatible types. Meaning that you don't need any tricks like common initial sequence. The strict aliasing rule simply states (6.5/7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,

This is the case here.

Furthermore, as mentioned in other answers, the effective type of the actual data here is `int`, since allocated storage yields no effective type and so it becomes the first type used for lvalue access. This too means that the compiler cannot assume that the pointers won't alias.

Furthermore, the strict aliasing rule gives an exception for lvalue access of members of structs and unions:

> an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members

And then you have the common initial sequence on top of that. As far as aliasing goes, this is as well-defined as can be.

---

**Regarding type punning:**

Your actual concern does not seem to be aliasing, but type punning through unions. This is vaguely guaranteed by C11 6.5.2.3/3:

> A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,95) and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue.

That's the normative text and it's badly written - nobody can understand how programs/compilers are supposed to behave based on this. The informative foot note 95) explains it well:

> 95) If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). This might be a trap representation.

Meaning in your case, you trigger a type conversion from one struct type to another compatible struct type. That's perfectly safe since they are the very same type and issues with alignment or traps do not apply.

Please note that C++ is different here.

Comment: _and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared
with the same name_ Does this mean the name of identifier? If so the corresponding members have different names: `i1 -> j1` and `i2 -> j2`.

Comment: @SomeName 2 unnamed structs in your question are not compatible, because their corresponding members indeed have different names. But the rule for unions speaks about common initial sequences which only requires members, not structs, to have compatible types. And non-structure, non-union, non-enumeration types such as `int` and `int` are compatible if they are the same, which holds for the fields of the structs.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I just suited the whole rule about what makes 2 structs compatible and as you can see, it does not mention member names, just declared types. Which makes the discussion about common initial sequence superfluous.

Comment: @Lundin _2 structs compatible and as you can see, it does not mention member names_ Maybe I misunderstood something, but it mentions member names: _if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with the same name_

Answer (score 1):

The C11 standard (n1570) states in the [footnote](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note87) on `[6.5 Expressions]/6` that:

> Allocated objects have no declared type.

And [`[6.5 Expressions]/6`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) states that:

> 6 The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any. If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

And you are also following the stated rules in [`[6.5 Expressions]/7`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) when you access the stored values for printing in the `printf` statement.

This combined with the citation you have provided from `N1570 6.5.2.3(p6)` which provides "One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions" makes this well-defined.

On the practical side, if you look at the [assembly generated](https://godbolt.org/z/w250RJ), you will find that this is what is actually happening.

> ```
>         push    rbp
>         mov     rbp, rsp
>         sub     rsp, 16
>         mov     eax, 8
>         mov     edi, eax
>         call    malloc
>         mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rax //Here
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8] //Here
>         mov     dword ptr [rax], 10      //Here 
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8] //Here
>         mov     dword ptr [rax + 4], 11  //Here 
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
>         mov     ecx, dword ptr [rax]
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
>         add     ecx, dword ptr [rax + 4]
>         movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
>         mov     esi, ecx
>         mov     al, 0
>         call    printf
>         xor     ecx, ecx
>         mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], eax # 4-byte Spill
>         mov     eax, ecx
>         add     rsp, 16
>         pop     rbp
>         ret
> .L.str:
>         .asciz  "%d\n"
> ```

Comment: _So the allocated memory in this case is two integers and does not have an effective type because you are not using an lvalue to store into them_ WUT? `u_ptr -> s1.i1` in `u_ptr -> s1.i1 = 10` is not an lvalue?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Removed that statement. Thank you. Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that.